# How use the google maps hand cursor in Python?

Tags: python, wxpython, cursor

I want to use the google maps hand cursor in Python but I don't know how to do it.
I've downloaded the cursor but I only get to use the hand open, I also have a event that "closes" the hand when clicked but I don't know how can I change the style cursor on it.

I say this because the google maps hand cursor has two style (the open and the closed hand).

If you don't know how to use the other style you can also tell me how can I create another cursor where the close hand is the default style. If I have that, I only change the cursor and it's done.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two cursors and change them on events as they need to be.

Comment: how can I get the other cursor? the one with the closed hand

Comment: add self contained code showing what are you doing, I will try to improve that

Comment: I've created a .cur file with an .png that I donwload from net and after that used the two cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just changing the cursor, i.e:

```
myFrame.SetCursor(closedCursor)
```

In the event handler for mouse-down? Then for mouse-up change it back again. `myFrame` is your container `wx.Frame`, and I suppose you already know how to load a cursor from a file.

Comment: offcourse I have that, the problem is that I can't get the closed hand cursor, how can I do it?

Comment: @aF: What do you mean by "get"? download? load into wxPython?

Comment: it was download, but I've created one with a .png file that I found :)